# Is it necessary to unregister a EntityModifier in AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine

I use AndEngine and the EntityModifier to animate some properties like the scale or the position of many Entities. Is it necessary to unregister the EntityModifiers after they are done or is it already the default behaviour?

And if it's necessary: Is it better to use

```
modifier.setAutoUnregisterWhenFinished(true);
```

or to call

```
entity.unregisterEntityModifier(modifier);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's been a while since I used AndEngine, but if memory serves, AutoUnregister is ON by default which worked great for my needs. As for your question - it shouldn't matter which method you use to unregister - If AutoUnregister is ON, then AndEngine makes the same call for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two Boolean that decide the modifiers life

protected boolean mFinished;
private boolean mAutoUnregisterWhenFinished = true;

As u can see mAutoUnregisterWhenFinished is true by default, also mFinished is set when the modifier is finished. and when the both of this booleans get true the below condition is worked to destroy the modifier.

```
if(modifier.isFinished() && modifier.isAutoUnregisterWhenFinished()) {
                this.remove(i);
            }
```

About your Question it depends on your

```
entity.unregisterEntityModifier(modifier);
```

the above code is used when u want to apply a new modifier to the sprite or entity.where as the

```
modifier.setAutoUnregisterWhenFinished(true);
```

is only applied when that modifier is finished. 
for example if u want to apply a movement to a sprite when u touch on it, you can use unregister modifier and apply new modifier.

Thanks